# What does it mean to rejoice with trembling in Psalm 2:11?

Tags: word-study, psalms

Psalm 2:11 KJV

> Serve the Lord with fear, and rejoice with trembling.

Somehow the above the text seems contradictory in the sense that how could one rejoice yet at the same time tremble.My understanding is that when one rejoices there is no need to tremble.

How can we understand this word play?

Answer (score 1):

I have personally observed, and experienced, joy so intense that it induces trembling.

Matthew Poole notes the following:

> **With trembling**: this is added to express the quality of this joy to which he calls them, and to distinguish it from that carnal and
> worldly rejoicing which is usually attended with security, and
> presumption, and licentiousness, and to warn them to take heed that
> they do not turn this grace of God into wantonness, nor slacken their
> dread of God’s tremendous majesty, and of his terrible judgments, if
> they should hereafter revolt from him, or rebel against him; but, on
> the contrary, work out their salvation with fear and trembling, as it
> is prescribed, Philippians 2:12: compare Matthew 28:8.